# Virtualizor KVM - Change Network Settings after VM Deployment

Tags: kvm, bridge

I'm doing a project to my virtualization module in computer science degree.

The professor is asking me to setup a bsd template in kvm that can be automatically setup in Virtualizor Web Panel.

I have successfully create a vm and configure the network with a bridge, but then the professor is asking me to create a template of that VM.

I see that I need to run a post install script, but the thing is I dont know how and where should I run that script!

I have a sh file that will change the **/etc/rc.conf** settings but the million euro question is how can I run that script with Virtualizor KVM :(

Anyone can help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run your script using Virtualizor. cause that's CSRF protected and not open-source!
But I think you can run the template making file directly.

```
/usr/local/virtualizor/tools/windows.php
```

Check their documentation here: [Create OS Template](http://www.virtualizor.com/wiki/Create_OS_Template)